# Set a minimum time value if selected date is the current date

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have two separate input fields of type date and type time. The user should not be able to select a `pickupDate` and `pickupTime` that has past (less than the current time).

I am able to set the minimum date so that the user cannot select a past date, however am having trouble with doing the same with the minimum `pickupTime`. Currently what is it doing, is that if I select a day in advance e.g. 26/05/2019, and the current time is 3:30 PM I cannot select any time before this 2:30 PM, 1:30 PM etc. as the minimum is the current time (not taking into account that the date is in the future). How do I make it so that only if the **current date** is selected, then it will set the `pickupTime` to have a minimum value (being the current time)?

**booking.html**

```
    <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="pickupDate">Pickup Date:</label>
        <input id="pickupDate" type="date" name="pickupDate" min="d" required>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-control-group">
        <label for="pickupTime">Pickup Time:</label>
        <input id="pickupTime" type="time" name="pickupTime" required>
    </div>


    <script>
        var d = new Date().toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        var time = new Date().toString("HH:mm"); //changed from HH:mm
        document.getElementById("pickupDate").value = d;        
        document.getElementById("pickupTime").value = time;     
        pickupDate.min = d;

        if(pickupDate.value == d) {
            pickupTime.min = time;
        }
    </script>
```

I expect if the current date is 25/05/2019 2:00PM :
- If the selected `pickupDate` is 25/05/2019, the `pickupTime` cannot be 1:00PM
- If the selected `pickupDate` is 26/05/2019, the `pickupTime` can be 1:00PM

**My table structure is:**

```
referenceNo VARCHAR(100)    
pickupDate  DATE
pickupTime  TIME
```

Comment: Where are the `pickupDate` and `pickupTime` objects come from? Are they defined elsewhere? Additionally,  what do they contain?

Comment: `new Date().toString("yyyy-MM-dd")` infers either you are using a library or think *Date.prototype.toString* accepts a format string. It doesn't, any supplied parameters are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly done that what you want but given an example that you can set a timer in your time control to restrict back entry.

```js
display_c(); 

function display_c(){
  var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
  var d = new Date();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  var s = d.getSeconds();
 
  if(h == '0') {h = 24;}
  //alert(h+":"+m +":" + s);
  var currentTime = h+":"+m +":" +s ; 

  document.getElementById('sct').innerHTML = currentTime;  
  document.getElementById('ct').value = currentTime;  
  display_c();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
 
<head>
 <meta charset=utf-8>
 <title>Current Time Display</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  <input type="time" id="ct">
  
  <span id='sct' ></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why have you included jQuery twice when your code doesn't use it?